# OpenCV FindContours return empty

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I run the find contours function againts this image but always return empty.

My Xamarin Android code:

```
  var frame = new Mat();

  bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  bitmapOptions.InScaled = false;

  var bitmapTemplateOrig = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.Resources, Resource.Drawable.abi_canny, bitmapOptions);
  OpenCV.Android.Utils.BitmapToMat(bitmapTemplateOrig, frame);
  bitmapTemplateOrig.Dispose();

  Imgproc.CvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.ColorRgba2gray);

  var contours = new List<MatOfPoint>();
  Imgproc.FindContours(frame, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RetrList, Imgproc.ChainApproxSimple, new Core.Point(0, 0));
  var size = contours.Count();  // returns 0 here?
```

My testing image already applied canny detection here.
[image: test image]

Any idea?

Comment: I am able to obtain 518 contours for half the size of this image. How are you running it?

Comment: Have no idea. I used Xamarin for Android. I updated my code in question.

Comment: @JeruLuke: Can you post your code?

Comment: I used python if it is OK....

Comment: Threshold the image after `Imgproc.CvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.ColorRgba2gray);`

Comment: @MinhNguyen were you successful?

Comment: @JeruLuke: unfortunately, stil stuck, return nothing :(

Comment: @MinhNguyen You have not performed binary threshold. Apply it before finding contour

Comment: How do I perform binary threshold ? I have the same problem, with Xamarin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code in python:

```
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_TREE, 1)

print 'Number of contours:', len(contours)

cv2.drawContours(img1, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imwrite("img1cnt.jpg", img1)
```

Result:

```
Number of contours: 518
```

[image]